# Update every record in a column of a table with a PHP generated UUID

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table called "partners" which contains a very large amount of contact information. After having extensively cleaned up the data from which I received it in, I've added a UUID column which I would ideally like to populate with UUID's via the PHP $generateobjectid=(uniqid('AGF'));

Is there a simple script I could write that would go through the database and enter in a uniqid for each and every row this one single time?

I'd prefer to keep the uniqid generated via PHP so that I can manage the prefix between the various entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use the mysql function UUID()

```
UPDATE XXX set FIELD=CONCAT('AGF',UUID())
```

Comment: I had certainly thought of that, however it is much longer... are there any limitations to the smaller UUID_Small? I had read somewhere that the PHP generated UUID was superior in terms of potential duplications. I'm a newb, though.

Comment: never heard of UUID_Small, its not in the mysql manual. "A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time" so you should be safe from collision.

Comment: sorry, i meant UUID_SHORT()

Comment: as long as your version supports it i see nothing against UUID_SHORT()